# How do I create a `glib::MainContext::channel()` outside of the `connect_activate()` and then pass it in?

Tags: rust, gtk, borrow-checker, gtk-rs

I am new to rust and GTK. I'd like to create a `glib::MainContext::channel()` pair prior to initializing my `gtk::Application`. I believe this can be thought of exactly like a `std::sync::mpsc`. And while I can create the rx/tx channel pair and save it, I'm not sure how to pass the `Receiver` into the `gtk::Application::connect_activate()` signal handler so that I can `.attach()` it.

For example, I've modified this [sample](https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk3-rs/blob/master/examples/cairo_threads/main.rs):

```rust
struct MyData {
    ready_tx: glib::Sender<i32>,
    //ready_rx: glib::Receiver<i32>,
}

fn setup() -> MyData {
    let (ready_tx, ready_rx) = glib::MainContext::channel(glib::Priority::default());
    MyData {
        ready_tx,
        //ready_rx,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data = setup();

    //
    // Setup other threads by cloning data.sender
    //

    let application = gtk::Application::new(
        Some("com.github.gtk-rs.examples.cairo_threads"),
        Default::default(),
    );

    application.connect_activate(move |app| {
        build_ui(&app, &data)
    });

    application.run();
}

fn build_ui(application: &gtk::Application, data: &MyData) {
    ...
    data.ready_rx.attach( {
        ...
    });
}
```

The above compiles and runs (ignoring the stubbed out `build_ui`) but has an obvious issue: `ready_tx` isn't actually included.

Doing so results in a "move occurs because `data.ready_rx` has type `glib::Receiver<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait'" inside `build_ui()`.

I want the ownership of the `Receiver<i32>` to transit from the `setup()` function, up to `main`, and eventually be consumed by the `build_ui()` function, but I'm not sure how to get there or what I'm missing. I'm not sure why `Copy` is needed and I know I can't `.clone()` the `Receiver`.

Any ideas?

I want to do this because I need to setup some additional threads first that will need references to the `Sender` well before I initialize the GTK GUI. I haven't found any good examples of creating a `glib::MainContext::channel()` pair outside of the `build_ui()` function.

Is there another approach I should consider?

UPDATE:

Thanks to @chayim-friedman's answer, the following modifications to the posted code does what I need:

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;

struct MyData {
    ready_tx: glib::Sender<i32>,
    ready_rx: Cell<Option<glib::Receiver<i32>>>,
}

fn setup() -> MyData {
    let (ready_tx, ready_rx) = glib::MainContext::channel(glib::Priority::default());
    MyData {
        ready_tx,
        ready_rx: Cell::new(Some(read_rx)),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = setup();

    //
    // Setup other threads by cloning data.sender
    //

    let application = gtk::Application::new(
        Some("com.github.gtk-rs.examples.cairo_threads"),
        Default::default(),
    );

    application.connect_activate(move |app| {
        build_ui(&app, &data)
    });

    application.run();
}

fn build_ui(application: &gtk::Application, data: &MyData) {
    ...
    data.ready_rx.take().unwrap().attach( {
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: You can't derive `Clone` for something that has fieldst hat don't implement it, doesn't just removing that derive work?

Comment: @cafce25 Yes, I can (and should) remove the `Clone` derivation. Thanks for catching that! I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the `Receiver` once, store an `Option<Receiver>` and `take().unwrap()` it in `build_ui()`, you will need a mutable reference to `MyData` for that.

If you cannot provide a mutable reference (which I believe is the case with GTK), you can store a [`Cell<Option<Receiver>>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.Cell.html), and `take().unwrap()` it. This only requires a shared reference, as `Cell` has interior mutability.

Comment: Yep! This seems to be what I needed to do. Thanks!